# How to save the Simple data in the firebase using vue.js?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

Suppose there are two fields that containing some text like first text-field contains the string "Apple" and the next text-field will contains the counting of the Apples and suppose the value of the count is 10 and on the submit button is clicked then how to send the data into the firebase database the code I'm using for the saving the emails and the password is :-

```
 <template>
  <div class="container">
   <div class= "row">
    <div class= "col-xs-12 co-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
     <h1>Http</h1>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Mail</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="email">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </template>

 <script>
   import firebase from 'firebase'
   var config = {
       apiKey: "]api_key",
       authDomain: "vuejs-http-11c9f.firebaseapp.com",
       databaseURL: "https://vuejs-http-11c9f.firebaseio.com",
       projectId: "vuejs-http-11c9f",
       storageBucket: "vuejs-http-11c9f.appspot.com",
       messagingSenderId: "Messaging_id"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    export default {
    data() {
     return{
        username:'',
        email:''
     };
   },
   methods:{
    submit(){
      // console.log(this.user.email)
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.username, this.email)
     .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      }).catch((err) => {
         console.log(err)
      });
    }
  }
 }
</ script>
```

What should the changes will applied in the above program that it will save my two text field data into the datbase of the firebase.

Firebase I'm using us 5.3.1 .

Answer (score 0):

For saving data in firebase database, you have usually two options.

1) cloud Firestore (currently in beta version)

2) Real time database

As cloud Firestore is in beta, i would suggest to go with real time database if your app will be in production soon.

so for storing it in firebase using real time database, you first need to create reference of firebase database like below

```
const databaseRef = firebase.database();
```

After that use this reference to set data like below

```
databaseRef.ref('fruitDetails/').set({
  fruitName: 'name of the fruit from text field',
  count: 'count from count text field'
});
```

Make sure to use the same reference of database in your whole app, if you don't want to create multiple databases.